# Нужен слайдер на чистом css + элементы управления (кнопки внизу и стрелки по бокам)

Tags: css, slider

Ищу по типу такого[image: слайдер на чистом css]

Нашел похожий, теперь нужно сделать как на фото:
1- стрелочки по бокам чтобы отображались на всех слайдах (на 1 и 4 четвертом одна пропадает)
2-  поменять их на вид как на фото (не знаю как их вообще искать и т.д.)
Прошу помощи, плохо соображаю еще

```css
 body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Slider wrapper*/
.css-slider-wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Slider */
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* each slide backgound color */  
.slide1 {
  background: #00bcd7;
  left: 0;
}
.slide2 {
  background: #009788;
  left: 100%
}
.slide3 {
  background: #ff5608;
  left: 200%
}
.slide4 {
  background: #607d8d;
  left: 300%;
}
.slider > div {
  text-align: center;
}
/* Slider inner slide effect */
.slider h2 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
}
.slider .button {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-500px);
  transform: translateX(-500px);
}
.slider h2, .slider .button {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
/* Next and Preive arrow */ 
.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  z-index: 55;
}
.control label {
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.control label:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.next {
  right: 1%;
}
.previous {
  left: 1%;
}
/* Slider Pagger */ 
.slider-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.slider-pagination label {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  margin: 0 2px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Slider Pagger arrow event */
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .next .numb2, 
.slide-radio2:checked ~ .next .numb3, 
.slide-radio3:checked ~ .next .numb4, 
.slide-radio2:checked ~ .previous .numb1, 
.slide-radio3:checked ~ .previous .numb2, 
.slide-radio4:checked ~ .previous .numb3 {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1
}
/* Slider Pagger event */
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page1, 
.slide-radio2:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page2, 
.slide-radio3:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page3, 
.slide-radio4:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page4 {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,1)
}
/* Slider slide effect */
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.slide-radio2:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.slide-radio3:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.slide-radio4:checked ~ .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide1 h2,  
.slide-radio2:checked ~ .slide2 h2,  
.slide-radio3:checked ~ .slide3 h2,  
.slide-radio4:checked ~ .slide4 h2,  
.slide-radio1:checked ~ .slide1 .button,  
.slide-radio2:checked ~ .slide2 .button,  
.slide-radio3:checked ~ .slide3 .button,  
.slide-radio4:checked ~ .slide4 .button {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.slider h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.slider > div {
  padding: 0 2%
}
.control label {
  font-size: 35px;
}
.slider .button {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
}

 .clearfix:after {  content: "."; display:block; font-size:0; line-height:0; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
 .clearfix { display:inline-block; }  
 * html .clearfix { height:1%; }
 .clearfix { display:block; }

 body {margin:0; background:#FFF url(../img/body.png); -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -moz-text-size-adjust:100%; padding:10px 2%; font:14px/24px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif  ; color:#000;} 
 #wrapper { background:#FFF; width:1200px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 0px #E7E7E7; border-top:5px solid #0088cc; border-radius:6px; box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed }
 #header { padding:30px 20px; border-bottom:solid 1px #e0e0e0; margin-bottom:20px; text-align:center; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
 #logo { display:inline-block; font-weight:300;  margin:0 0 0px; font-size:30px; line-height:24px;  color:#000; text-decoration:none; position:relative;  }
 #logo span{ color:#0088cc;}
 
 section { padding:0 20px 20px}
 
    h2, h1{ font:300 22px/30px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0}
    h1{ font-size:30px; line-height:40px; }
 h2 span{color:#0088cc;}
 .classname { display:block;  padding:20px;  border:solid 2px #CCC; text-align:center;}
    
    hr{ padding:0; margin:50px 0; height:1px; border:0; background:rgba(0,0,0,.2); box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.8)  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<title>Pure css based fullscreen slider Demo</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Pure css based fullscreen slider Demo">
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="css-slider-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">
  <div class="slider-pagination">
    <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="next control">
    <label for="slider_1" class="numb1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="numb2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="numb3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="numb4"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></label>
  </div>
  <div class="previous control">
    <label for="slider_1" class="numb1"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="numb2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="numb3"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="numb4"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></label>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide1">
    <div>
      <h2>Css Based slider</h2>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide2">
    <div>
      <h2>CSS Slider without use of any javascript or jQuery</h2>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide3">
    <div>
      <h2>Full screen animation slider</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide4">
    <div>
      <h2>css3 slider</h2>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: слайдер на чистом css, даже если это и возможно он будет очень херовым

Comment: благодарю за ваше мнение, учтемс ))

Comment: Евгения, используйте для этого `JavaScript`. Слайдер на `CSS` это особый трюк, его неудобно писать и редактировать, если нужно. Для новичка легче будет это писать на `JavaScript`

Comment: Я вас понял. У меня есть уже готовый на джс. Но нужно сделать именно на чистом ксс ))

Comment: добавил и жду помощи)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Slider wrapper*/

.css-slider-wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* Slider */

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* each slide backgound color */

.slide1 {
  background: #00bcd7;
  left: 0;
}

.slide2 {
  background: #009788;
  left: 100%
}

.slide3 {
  background: #ff5608;
  left: 200%
}

.slide4 {
  background: #607d8d;
  left: 300%;
}

.slider>div {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Slider inner slide effect */

.slider h2 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 120%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(500px);
  transform: translateX(500px);
}

.slider .button {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-500px);
  transform: translateX(-500px);
}

.slider h2,
.slider .button {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms, -webkit-transform 800ms;
  transition: transform 800ms, opacity 800ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}


/* Next and Preive arrow */

.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  z-index: 55;
}

.control label {
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.control label:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.next {
  right: 1%;
}

.previous {
  left: 1%;
}


/* Slider Pagger */

.slider-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.slider-pagination label {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 0 2px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Slider Pagger arrow event */

.slide-radio1:checked~.previous .numb1, /* ДОБАВИЛ */
.slide-radio1:checked~.next .numb2,
.slide-radio2:checked~.next .numb3,
.slide-radio3:checked~.next .numb4,
.slide-radio2:checked~.previous .numb1,
.slide-radio3:checked~.previous .numb2,
.slide-radio4:checked~.previous .numb3,
.slide-radio4:checked~.next .numb4 /* ДОБАВИЛ */ {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1
}


/* Slider Pagger event */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider-pagination .page1,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slider-pagination .page2,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slider-pagination .page3,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slider-pagination .page4 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
}


/* Slider slide effect */

.slide-radio1:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.slide-radio2:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-radio3:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.slide-radio4:checked~.slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}

.slide-radio1:checked~.slide1 h2,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide2 h2,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide3 h2,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide4 h2,
.slide-radio1:checked~.slide1 .button,
.slide-radio2:checked~.slide2 .button,
.slide-radio3:checked~.slide3 .button,
.slide-radio4:checked~.slide4 .button {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .slider h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .slider>div {
    padding: 0 2%
  }
  .control label {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .slider .button {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slider-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">
  <div class="slider-pagination">
    <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
  </div>
  
  <!-- ЗДЕСЬ ВНУТРИ LABEL ПОЛОЖИШЬ НУЖНЫЕ ТЕБЕ СТРЕЛКИ --> 
  <div class="next control">
    <label for="slider_1" class="numb1">&gt;</label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="numb2">&gt;</label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="numb3">&gt;</label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="numb4">&gt;</label>
  </div>
  <div class="previous control">
    <label for="slider_1" class="numb1">&lt;</label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="numb2">&lt;</label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="numb3">&lt;</label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="numb4">&lt;</label>
  </div>
  <!-- ЗДЕСЬ ВНУТРИ LABEL ПОЛОЖИШЬ НУЖНЫЕ ТЕБЕ СТРЕЛКИ --> 
  
  
  <div class="slider slide1">
    <div>
      <h2>Css Based slider</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide2">
    <div>
      <h2>CSS Slider without use of any javascript or jQuery</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide3">
    <div>
      <h2>Full screen animation slider</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slide4">
    <div>
      <h2>css3 slider</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: можно уточнить у вас по поводу стрелок перелистывания сбоку у слайдов, как можно их оставить на всех слайдах ( а то пропадает на 1 и 4 одна)?

Comment: @EvgeniyReva я там написал комменты где поменял.

Comment: благодарю сердечно)

Comment: @EvgeniyReva ну и стоит сказать, что подобные слайдеры нужны лишь для того, что бы показать скилуху его автора. На js это делается в пару строк.

Comment: Я не понял ни один вопрос.

Comment: 1) Прошу вас добавить шапку html кода (doctype-body) что вы использовали, с моей, что представлена выше, при добавлении вашего кода, 1 из 2 боковых стрелок пропадает на 1 и 4 слайде соответственно. Не могу сообразить в чем дело, где ошибка. 2) Не подскажете, как сделать карусель из этих слайдов: чтобы боковыми стрелками я мог переключать по кругу все слайды, а не "стопориться" на 1 или 4 соответственно. Ну или как правильно сформулировать запрос в поисковик, не могу найти - не знаю что искать :)

Comment: @EvgeniyReva вы не добавили в свой css файл то что я добавил. Посмотрите внимательно, я в тех местах написал комментарий _ДОБАВИЛ_

Comment: @EvgeniyReva на второй вопрос у меня нет ответа и я не хочу в этой верстке разбираться.

Comment: благодарю за помощь)